# Jtextpane copy coloured text and paste

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtextpane, htmleditorkit

I have a JTextPane which displays colored text . I use the followong piece of code to get text from JTextPane.

```
String temp = pane.getDocument().getText(0,pane.getDocument().getLength());
```

However  when i try to set the temp variable content to pane again,

```
pane.select(0,pane.getDocument().getLength());
pane.replaceSelection(temp);
```

by this way i lose the color and get white text. Is there anyway where i can maintain the color of text without copying the content to clipboard.

Please help.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1357759?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

Actually it depends on EditorKit you use. The first part returns text (with styled info) of the selected fragment. E.g. in the RTFEditorKit it would be rtf content of the document's fragment.

The second part is not correct. Replace selection can't process the content properly. I guess in case of the RTFEditorKit it would be all the text with formatting inserted in the pane.

I would use

```
pane.setText(temp);
```

instead. If you need to insert the styled fragment use `kit.read(...)` passing the `temp` in the call

You can try the [Kit](http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html) as alternative of the default RTFEditorKit and see what happens

UPDATE: Sorry original comment was incorrect a bit. The code should be

```
 pane.getEditorKit().read(
      new StringReader(temp), 
      pane.getDocument(), 
      pane.getDocument().getLength())
```

Comment: Can you please give a small example.

Comment: So i can use `String temp = pane.getDocument().getText(0,pane.getDocument().getLength());` to get the text with style info and instead of replaceSelection i need to use your UPDATE code?? Am sorry i couldn't get it.

Comment: Yes. You can use your code to get selection and pass it to my code from the example.